# A weird looking pip freeze

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-composer

I'm inside one of my Kubernetes workers for google cloud composer, and I try to do a pip freeze to get a list of python dependencies.

Except this pip freeze is not like the ones I'm used to seeing.

i.e :
What you expect to see after a `pip freeze`

```
absl-py==0.10.0
agate==1.6.1
agate-dbf==0.2.2
agate-excel==0.2.3
...
```

What I get :

```
apache-beam @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-1.10.12/python3/apache_beam-2.23.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
apispec @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-1.10.12/python3/apispec-1.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
appdirs @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-1.10.12/python3/appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
argcomplete @ file:///usr/local/lib/airflow-pypi-dependencies-1.10.12/python3/argcomplete-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
...
```

What is this pip freeze format, and how do I recreate it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+weird+freeze

Comment: Thank you for the link. Also, the errors had nothing to do with pip freeze.